# How to loop the textbox.insert

Tags: loops, sockets, customtkinter

I'm trying to make it so that the GUI prints the message that is sent from the gui to the server which works once if you remove the for loop however if. you add the for loop the textbox never inserts the message that is sent, how could this be fixed?

```
while True:
chat.update_idletasks()
chat.update()
try:
    received_message = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    for i in received_message():
        if received_message:
            textbox.insert("end", f"Received: {received_message}\n")
            textbox.configure(state="disabled", text_color="black")  # configure textbox to be read-only
except Exception as e:
    pass
```